# getting low image quality from the camera after Lollipop while using bitmap factory

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera-intent, bitmapfactory

I use surface view for camera operation, After the image is captures am passing the image data to storeByteImage method.
But for certain devices or android lolipop version onwards am getting low resolution image.
In some new devices I get only 1/4 of the image captured.

```
public boolean storeByteImage(Context mContext, byte[] imageData, int quality) {

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;

            Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);

            _getdate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            _getdate.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            _getdate.layout(0, 0, _getdate.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    _getdate.getMeasuredHeight()); //  set the layout of  the date in the image
            _getdate.buildDrawingCache(true);
            _getdate.buildDrawingCache();
            try {
                textimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(_getdate.getDrawingCache());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            _getdate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); //  clear drawing
                                                    // cache

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            //  the image height and width
            int width, height;
            height = myImage.getHeight();
            width = myImage.getWidth();

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bitmap);
            myImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage, width, height, true);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, null);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(textimage, matrix, null);


                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.sdpath_files_dir) + IMAGEFILE_EXT_JPG);   
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the image data? `(Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");`?

Comment: @MichaelDodd thanks for reply.

I use camera.takePicture, hence the callback function I get image data that is passed to storeByteImage.

Comment: "*get only 1/4 of the image captured*" because you asked for `options.inSampleSize = 2`.

Comment: Note that `myImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage, width, height, true);` is a NOP, according to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

Comment: And you probably censored out the piece that compresses this bitmap to fileOutputStream.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for reply
height = myImage.getHeight();
width = myImage.getWidth(); 

Am getting low resolutions only. –

Comment: You create myImage scaled down x2 from the JPEG you receive in onPictureTaken()

Comment: @AlexCohn
What should it suppose to have for better quality image.

Comment: Try to keep `options.inSampleSize = 1`

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks.. It works and am getting high pixel. Need to test more Will update here once done.